# ASP.NET MVC 4, need help to get my GenericRepository to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern

I created a genericrepository

here's my code:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> : IDisposable where T: class 
{
    void Save();

    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T: class 
{
    private readonly DSContext _context;

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        _context = new DSContext();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }


    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

here's my employeeRepository. its empty , nothing there, but the employeeRepository is inherited from GenericRepository. I am assuming that "Save, Insert, Delete" should be available in employeeRepository. but they are not there, when I use employeeRepository in my service layer.

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{ 

}

public class EmployeeRepository: GenericRepository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
{
    public EmployeeRepository():base()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you are using `IEmployeeRepository` in your service layer, not EmployeeRepository, and since IEmployeeRepository does **not** have any of those methods, it makes sense.

You are coding against the interface, not the implementation, so while the actual object does have those methods, you won't be able to call them without resorting to reflection. You would need to have IEmployeeRepository inherit from `IGenericRepository<T>` as well to get those other methods.